# From the limit of a function to its value and its derivatives at a point.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a infinitely differentiable function such tha

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2f(x)+2x^2-6\cos x}{3x^2}=0.\tag 1$$

I have to calculate the following quantity: $$f(0)+f'(0)+f^{''}(0).$$

**My solution.**

Since $(1)$ hold then $$f(x)\to -x^2+3\cos x\quad\text{for}\; x\to 0$$ and therefore for $x\to 0$ we have that $f(x)\to 3$.

Now, $f'(x)\to -2x-3\sin x$ when $x\to 0$ and therefore $$f'(x)\to 0\quad\text{for}\; x\to0.$$ In the same way $f^{''}(x)\to -2-3\cos x$ for $x\to 0$ and then $f^{''}(x)\to -5$.

Combining all the obtained results, we have that $$f(0)+f^{'}(0)+f^{''}(0)=3+0-5=-2.$$

> **Question**
> I'm not sure if the procedure is correct, it seems to me that I'm using convergence of functions. Is this type of procedure correct? Otherwise, how should I proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would’ve approximated the derivatives using l’Hopital on the original limit instead of deducing the derivatives from the approximation of the argument of the limit. Reason being that an oscillating function could still approximate another function while the derivatives won’t follow.

Comment: @AnneBauval I deleted my comment, as I added an answer.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Thank you, I just saw it. I did the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $f(x)\to -x^2+3\cos x$ (as $x\to0$) means nothing. The correct formulation is $f(x)+x^2−3\cos x→0.$
- It does not imply $f′(x)+2x+3\sin x→0,$ which itself does not imply $f′′(x)+2+3\cos x→0.$
- A correct and simpler method is to translate the hypothesis into:
  $$f(x)=-x^2+3\cos x+o(x^2),$$
  which (given that $f$ is twice differentiable at $0$) is equivalent to
  $$f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}2f''(0)=-x^2+3\left(1-\frac{x^2}2\right)$$
  i.e.
  $$f(0)=3,\quad f'(0)=0,\quad f''(0)=-5.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your method does not really make a lot of sense, you say "$f(x)\to -x^2+3\cos x \text{ for } x\to 0$", assuming by this you mean that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) +x^2-3\cos x=0$ you can say that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=f(0)=3$ by the continutiy of $f$, but in no way can you make the claim that $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)+2x+3\sin x=0$.

To see why you can not just make that claim note that for example $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)-2x=0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(x)-2\neq 0$!

To find the value of the sum, you can use L'Hopitals rule instead, for example to compute $f'(0)$, you differentiate the numerator and denominator of the quotient to get that $\lim_{x\to0}2f'(x)+4x+6 \sin x=0$ from which you can conclude by the continuty of $f'(0)$ that $f'(0)=0$. Similarly by differentiating the original quotient twice you can get $f''(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Always try limit laws at first. We can write $$f(x) =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac {2f(x)+2x^2-6\cos x} {3x^2}\cdot 3x^2-2x^2+6\cos x\right)$$ Taking limits as $x\to 0$ and using continuity of $f$ we get $f(0)=3$.

Next we have $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$ The fraction under limit equals $$\frac {2f(x)+2x^2-6\cos x}{3x^2}\cdot\frac{3x^2}{2x}-\frac{3-3\cos x+x^2} {x}$$ and thus $f'(0)=0$.

Lastly the limit $$f''(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x) - f'(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x}$$ is known to exist. By L'Hospital's Rule the following limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2f(x)-6}{x^2}$$ also exists and equals $f''(0)$. The above limit equals the limit of $$\frac{2f(x)+2x^2-6\cos x} {3x^2}\cdot 3-\frac{6-6\cos x+2x^2}{x^2}$$ and thus $f''(0)=-5$.